# C#. Осуществить слияние двух коллекций в одну, отсортировать, а затем разбить по условию

Tags: c#, алгоритм, linq

Есть два типа (условно):

```
public class ItemNumber
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Common { get;set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}


public class ItemString
{
    public string Common { get;set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Есть две коллекции, заполненные данными:

```
// Они заполнены данными
var numbers = new List<ItemNumber>(); 
var letters = new List<ItemString>();
```

Необходимо (очередность выполнения шагов здесь может быть совершенно любая):

1. вставить элементы коллекции `numbers` в коллекцию `letters`;
2. отсортировать полученные `letters` по свойству `Order`;
3. разбить коллекцию `letters` на подколлекции, где границами разбиения
   будут (**внимание!**) те элементы из `numbers`, которые мы вставляли и у
   которых значение `Numbers = 4` (к примеру), при этом сами эти элементы, у которых `Numbers = 4` не должны включаться в результирующую коллекцию.

Раньше мне не нужно было осуществлять разбиение коллекции по условию (см. *п.3*), только *п.1* и *п.2*. Я это делал с помощью LINQ таким образом:

```
private static IReadOnlyCollection<ItemString> MergeCollections(IReadOnlyCollection<ItemNumber> numbers, IReadOnlyCollection<ItemString> letters)
{
    var result = new List<ItemString>(letters);

    result.AddRange(numbers.Select(p => new ItemString
    {
        Common = p.Common,
        Order = p.Order
    }));

    result = result.OrderBy(p => p.Order).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

И вот сижу мучаю эту задачу, как лучше всего это сделать. Есть идея это сделать через цикл по двум переменным, но пока эта идея смутная. Может, вы подскажете оптимальные решения такой задачи? Может, это возможно сделать с помощью LINQ? Если нет, то хотел бы увидеть подробное описание алгоритма.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

даный код несколько читабельнее приведенного в вопросе:

```
var items = new List<ItemNumber>(ItemNumberList);

// по -1 мы можем определить что это конвертированный элемент
// и не будем думать что 0 это значение
var tmp = itemStringList
    .Select( a => new ItemNumber{Common= a.Common, Order= a.Order, Number= -1});

itemsList.AddRange(tmp);

itemsList = itemsList.OrderBy(p => p.Order);
```

по поводу разбиения не вкурил что же там имелось ввиду и как разбивать. Если границами выступают Numbers = 4, а отсортировано у нас по Order то можно предположить что границ разделения может быть куча....

например ситуация:

```
{common="asdf", Order=1, Number = -1}
{common="asdf", Order=2, Number = 4} //граница разделиния
{common="asdf", Order=3, Number = 2}
{common="asdf", Order=4, Number = 4} //граница разделиния
{common="asdf", Order=5, Number = -1}
{common="asdf", Order=6, Number = 4} //граница разделиния
{common="asdf", Order=7, Number = 6}
```

уточни условия разбиения или условия того как могут эти итемы заполнятся.

---

upd:

```
var ranges = itemsList.Where(a => a.number == 4).Select(b => (itemsList.IndexOf(b))).ToList();

if(ranges[0] != 0)
    ranges.insertAt(0,0);

var lastIndex = itemsList.lenght - 1;

if(ranges.Last() != lastIndex)
    ranges.Add(lastIndex);
```

Итак что мы получили: список рейнджей 0 - первое вхождение, первое вхождение - второе вхождение, второе - третье.... предпоследнее - последнее.

дальше мы перебираем попарно эти индексы в цикле...

И если рейндж >= 1 то создаем новый лист, заполняем его:

```
var tmpList = itemsList.GetRange(rangeBegin, rangeEnd);
```

и помещаем его в лист листов result как следующий элемент.

```
//var result = List<List<ItemNumber>>()
result.Add(tmpList);
```

в приведенном коде могут быть мелкие синтаксические ошибки т.к. не имею доступа к вижуалке :) остачу логики допишешь сам

Comment: Ты все правильно понял. Границ разбиения будет столько, сколько элементов с Number = 4. Чтобы показать, как они должны мержиться, проще это дело нарисовать на бумаге, чем описывать текстом или кодом. Другими словами, мы вставляем элементы предварительно отсортированной коллекции `numbers` в отсортированную `letters`, при этом вставляем в нужные места. А если доходит дело до #4, то мы его не вставляем и делим коллекцию в текущей точке. Текстом реально сложно это описать

Comment: Это задание - часть реального проекта. Вставка элементов с признаком `-1` выглядит как костыль. Ведь -1 - это может быть вполне валидное значение.

Comment: если -1 может быть валидным, то тогда лучше нулейбл инт использовать и присваивать нулл

Comment: я расписал логику, дальше допишешь сам

Comment: Вот эта идея уже годная! Спасибо, я попробую и приму ответ, когда сделаю.

Comment: как успехи? Справился?

Comment: В процессе пока. Сегодня должен сделать, поэтому отпишусь сегодня/завтра

Comment: Идея разбить на индексы зашла. Метод GetRange у списка очень крутой. Только он работает не по сигнатуре `(rangeBegin, rangeEnd)`, а `(rangeBegin, rangeSize)`.

Comment: ну, писал по памяти) Я черти сколько не садился за шарп)

Comment: И еще, слияние двух коллекций я сделал на стороне `sql` с помощью `union`, поэтому задача оставалась лишь разбить коллекцию на подколлекции. Без вынесения логики слияния в `sql` метод выглядел ну просто нечитабельно :)

Comment: Спасибо anyway, твой совет помог